# Dedicated Library Folder in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea, libraries, java

Is it possible to create a dedicated folder for Libraries in IntelliJ IDEA like we have in NetBeans (creating new project you can enable it so it can automatically store all libraries there and then add them to VCS).

We need to share libraries among other computers via VCS so that others don't have to setup their environment before getting a code or adding a library after updating their code. We also need to make sure that the setup will work on Windows, Mac and Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a [Global Library](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/libraries-global-libraries-and-the-configure-library-dialog.html) that can be used in different projects.